# oracle, number of lines inserted/updated

Tags: c#, oracle

in c#, I try to insert and update table using following lines :

```
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(query, connection);
da.Fill(ds);
```

This works.

But, I need to know how to get the number of lines inserted on update. query is something like

```
insert into someTable Values(...)
```

Comment: You are getting dataset?

Comment: then have you tried do ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count?

Comment: with an insert query, tables[0] does not exists

Comment: No you didnt get my point.I am saying after you load the ds what is in the ds object?

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to know the record set count without running a separate count(*) query. This is by design. The DataReader and DataAdapter are forward-only, read only.**

You can try an alternative approach like below to get the affected rows.

```
public bool UploadBulkData(List<CustomerDTO> bulkData)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;
        try
        {

            string query = @"insert into PCMS.Customer ( surname, firstName, emailAddress) values 
                            (:surname, :firstName, :emailAddress)";
            oracleConnection.Open();
            using (var command = oracleConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = query;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.BindByName = true;
              // In order to use ArrayBinding, the ArrayBindCount property
              // of OracleCommand object must be set to the number of records to be inserted
                command.ArrayBindCount = bulkData.Count;
                command.Parameters.Add(":surname", OracleDbType.Varchar2, bulkData.Select(c => c.Surname).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                command.Parameters.Add(":firstName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, bulkData.Select(c => c.FirstName).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                command.Parameters.Add(":emailAddress", OracleDbType.Varchar2, bulkData.Select(c => c.EmailAddress).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                **result is what you need**
            }

        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            //Log error thrown
        }
        finally
        {
            oracleConnection.Close();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```